# NuGet Server for .NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

The [NuGet.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/) package is used to create a ASP.NET MVC NuGet server and it works just fine. There is another package [NuGet.Server.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server.Core/) that is expected to do the same when hosted within a ASP.NET Core (perhaps 1.0 or 1.1?).

The first one creates 'Packages' folder right beneath the main folder used as a package repository.
No such things happens after installing the Core version. I tried both root and a dedicated folder. Googling a bit, I found no info about installing the package and integrating it in a ASP.NET Core app.

Has anyone succeeded in installing the Core version? Also, there's another version [NuGet.Server.V2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server.V2/) which depends on NuGet.Server.Core, however it requires .NET Framework 4.6.1. This makes me think that **NuGet.Server.Core is not targetting .NET Core** at all.

If so, the name must be somewhat misleading, I guess...

Comment: `.Core` is a suffix that MSFT is using sometimes and only means "core-functionality". They have for example `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core` that is the core-functionalities of `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi`.

Answer (score 17):

Yes, this is the answer:

[image]

No .NET Core whatsoever! Just .NET Framework 4.6.1. Not a big discovery but a **warning** to all devs who, like me, were (and, more importantly, will be!) **misled** by 'Core' in the package's name.

Comment: That's a shame there's no official NuGet server for Linux.

Comment: Is this really still happening in 2023??

Comment: @Chris Yes. Recently I checked it again. This is why I use BaGet even under Ubuntu. :(

Answer (score 6):

Here's a 3rd party option (free)

https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet

Comment: Hey! Do you have some experience with using BaGet? I have this question https://github.com/loic-sharma/BaGet/issues/293 if you (or anyone else reading that) have time, please, help me with that :)

Answer (score 1):

Nuget.Server.Core seems to be one of the dependencies of Nuget.Server. So it's not a .NET Core project. Guess that's one of those snags you run into when you call your framework "Core". :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use BaGet.

There is my article about that.

Check this :

[Create your own NuGet server and package feed](https://medium.com/@onurvatan/net-core-custom-nuget-server-baget-on-docker-b763a3c7a276)