# Private Nuget server for asp.net core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

[Existing related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568833/nuget-server-for-net-core)

I want to create a asp.net core application which can be hosted in linux platform which could be used as private nuget repository.

Idea is via this app user can upload nuget packages and in turn to have an url which could be used a nuget package source.

For ***.Net Framework*** there is already ***NugetPackage*** called [Nuget.Server](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server/) from ***.NET Foundation***

However, this does not seem to work in .Net core application.

Even the nuget package [Nuget.Server.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server.Core/) does not seem to work for .net core application.

It would be nice if there was something like Nuget.Server for .Net core application too but nevertheless as a work around this is what I tried

```
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "lib", "NugetPackages")),
                RequestPath = "/Packages"
            });

            app.UseDirectoryBrowser(new DirectoryBrowserOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", "lib", "NugetPackages")),
                RequestPath = "/Packages"
            });

            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=FileManager}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

Here is the url that is mapped
[image: Nuget[4]]

But using that url as nugetpackage source does not work.

I have my asp.net core app running and I have setup nuget source

[image]

But I get an error saying

```
[local] The V2 feed at 'http://localhost:59614/packages/Search()?$filter=IsLatestVersion&searchTerm=''&targetFramework=''&includePrerelease=false&$skip=0&$top=26&semVerLevel=2.0.0' returned an unexpected status code '404 Not Found'.
```

My idea was to have an app(site) from where user can upload nuget packages and I store them in a folder (NugetPackages in this case). And then have a url (pointing to the location where all the packages are uploaded) which could be used as package source in Nuget

Comment: Could you be a bit more precise than _Even the nuget package Nuget.Server.Core does not seem to work for .net core application_. But typically you can use any network or filesystem directory as nuget source

Comment: Sounds like you might want [local NuGet feeds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/hosting-packages/local-feeds). Which I found after less than 10 seconds of Googling. Did you do any research before you asked your question?

Comment: Also, if you read the https://www.nuget.org/packages/NuGet.Server.Core/ dependencies you'll quickly see that its not meant for (ASP).NET Core. It's just named core as in "Shared library"

Comment: A lot of people here in the comments not understanding that you pull `NuGet.Server` into an empty asp.net application and it quickly lets you have a server that talks the NuGet *REST* APIs, the same as NuGet.org.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Question is about ASP.NET Core and neither of the two linked ones are ported for it as far as I can see from the dependencies (though `NuGet.Server.Core` is just another dependency of `NuGet.Server`)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever And who here in the comments doesn't seem to know that? That package is designed for ASP.NET, not ASP.NET Core, which is what the question was about.

Comment: @mason - the people talking about *filesystem access*

Comment: I have updated my question maybe that will help

Comment: Maybe my question formulation is wrong. What I was trying to say is would have been nice if there was as library like Nuget.Server that would work for core too. But since I didn't find any, I was thinking of a workaround but that doesnt work

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well I'm the only one talking about using the file system as a NuGet repository, and I was aware that you can utilize NuGet.Server for ASP.NET. I'm also aware that's irrelevant, as the question asked about .NET Core or just using the filesystem. So I'm not really sure what point you're trying to make here.

Comment: If you use VSTS or TFS you could install the Package Management plugin which lets you host private Nuget feeds (and other types of packages too e.g. npm). https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/overview?view=vsts . It's free for the first 5 users. No idea what scale you're operating at but it might be an option instead of coding your own or filesystem access (which is comparatively slow in my experience, esp. if you use a network share.)

Comment: @ADyson I don't use VSTS or TFS I am using gitlab

Comment: You could create a free VSTS account and use it just for that, I think.

Comment: @ADyson Thing is we want to have it private. Would that be possible with VSTS? Maybe you could give some hint. If you know some tutorials I could foloow

Comment: @Tseng Hope you understood my question now after I made an update

Comment: Yes you can set it either public or private. It's really trivial to set up and then instructions about things like how to connect to the feed are contained within VSTS once you activate the Package Management plugin and create a new feed. You don't really need a tutorial beyond what's already in the Microsoft documentation. Visit the link I gave you earlier and have a quick read, and also read this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/package/get-started-nuget?view=vsts

Comment: @Cybercop: What I think you're not getting is that the NuGet package isn't a library, it's a bootstrapping package that turns an blank ASP.NET MVC project into a NuGet server. It's based on the code for the *actual* nuget.org server, which was built on ASP.NET MVC. It doesn't work in Core and *won't* work in Core, because that's not how the website was built. If they ever decide to redo nuget.org on ASP.NET Core, maybe they'll then release a similar package for Core, but until that happens, nada.

Comment: @Cybercop: As far as VSTS goes, yes, the NuGet feed is private. We use it at my org. It's not completely free though. For a small shop like ours it ends up being free, because I think they give you a certain number of seats free, but it may end up costing for larger shops.